# React firebase not working properly with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I am getting error with this promise thing when i copy the code to some file like test.js and run, it works absolutely fine. but when i put the promise inside the react component if gives me error like

```
GET http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_database.js?t=1689256991515&v=cb04d5a7 net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)
lobby-screen.tsx:19     GET http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?t=1689256991515&v=b4bf525b net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)
```

without the promise the react works fine and outside the react the function works perfectly fine but when i put them together it doesnt work. I am tired fixing this.. Help me!!!

```
export const LobbyScreen = () => {
    // Listen for real-time changes in the data

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Initialize Firebase app
    let data;
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // Initialize database
    const db = getDatabase();
    // Reference to the specific location in the database
    const dbRef = ref(db, 'lobbies/0266');
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        data = snapshot.val();
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        console.log('No data available');
        reject();
      }
    })
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  return (
    <>
    hello world
    </>
  )
  
};
```

and yeah i have imported all the required modules and configs

I tried eveything from usestate async but not able to fix it so help me out

Comment: You should really put the `new Promise` inside of a `useEffect` if you're going to put it inside the component. The way it is now, it will execute on every render. That could be one of your problems.